# Write artibrary text at the end of horizontal bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib, and for the last 3 days I've been trying to make a very simple horizontal bar graph:
[image: unfinished graph]
In `Y` it carries a `products` list, in `X` `days_prod`, which is the number of days left for a specific product.
What I can't do is to add at the end of each bar the date the product is finished, which is obtained in `eo_inv`.
I know there are several posts on this topic in this forum, but I can't figure out how to adapt them to my needs.
Here is the code:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

days_prod = [292, 268, 273, 249, 191, 251]
prods = ['milk', 'butter', 'curd', 'panner', 'cheese', 'yogurt']

eo_inv = [
    str(date.today() + timedelta(days=x-1))
    for x in days_prod
]
# at 2023/10/17 eo_inv results in:
# eo_inv = ['2024-08-03', '2024-07-10', '2024-07-15', '2024-06-21', '2024-04-24', '2024-06-23']

plt.barh(prods, days_prod)

plt.title('Inventory')
plt.xlabel('Days Left')
plt.ylabel('Products')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does `bar_label` help? https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label

Comment: Code & plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqtr2.png

Comment: `plt.bar_label(plt.gca().containers[0], labels=eo_inv, label_type='center')` [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFvXh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like iterating over all your entries in `days_prod` and adding the corresponding entry in `eo_inv` at the end of the bar:

```
plt.xlim(0, max(days_prod)*1.3)
for i, day in enumerate(days_prod):
    plt.text(day, i, eo_inv[i])
```